# checking if a string is a palindrome not working properly

Tags: python

For some reason it works great but on some sentences that are palindrome it says they are not

```
palindrome = input("Enter a word: ")
palindrome = palindrome.lower()
palindrome.replace(" ", "")
if palindrome == palindrome[::-1]:
    print("OK")
else:
    print("NOT")
```

An example:"Mr Owl ate my metal worm"
but on other sentences it works good and i don't understand whats different 
please help me btw the level of the code needs to be at this level

Comment: Don't post images post your code as text.

Comment: Ensure all spaces are removed and all words are lowercase

Comment: `palindrome.replace(' ','')` doesn't replace string in-place it returns new string.

Comment: Do this `palindrome=palindrome.replace(' ','')`

Comment: ohh got it thank you so much totally forgot about it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The replace() method won't replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55438468/the-replace-method-wont-replace)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using replace whitespace ( if they are not require much ) then, you can convert the word to list of words sperated on whitespace and then create a new word joining all word inside the list and reverse it to check if the sentence is palindrome or not

here is code

```
palindrome = input("enter the word ")
palindrome = ''.join(palindrome.split()).lower()

if palindrome == palindrome[::-1]:
    print("OK")
else:
    print("NOT")
```

without using `join`

```
palindrome = input("enter the word ")
new_palin = ''
for chars in palindrome:
    if chars != ' ' :
        new_palin+=chars

new_palin = new_palin.lower()
if new_palin == new_palin[::-1]:
    print("OK")

else:
    print("NOT")
```

Comment: i can but the problem isn't in the replace.  the replace works and it works with other sentences also cant use the join command so the replace is the only way i have to get rid of the spaces but i don't think that the problem is in the spaces anyway.

Comment: ok , just updated solution if you can use for implemetation of replace